# Can GCC be used to compile to customized platforms?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, platform

Let's assume that we have a new platform X.
Can we just modify GCC so it can compile C/C++ for that platform? If so, what and how big are those changes?

Comment: Yes, it's called porting. And it's a rather daunting task unless your platform is very similar to an existing one. Consider LLVM.

Comment: If the new platform is very similar to an existing one, then it might just need to be rebuilt. Do a Google search for e.g. cross compiling.

Comment: Yes you can modify GCC to compile for your "new platform X". How much effort that requires depends on: What is this "new platform X"? Is it it derived from an existing architecture? Or is it something you've designed from scratch?

Comment: My guess is that if you have to ask, you're not the person to do it.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done, but it would be a very large task if this is a completely new architecture.

Some of the things you'd have to do:

- Make the C compiler generate assembly code for your processor
- Write an assembler capable of assembling said assembly code (i.e. port GAS)
- (Possibly) extend the linker (ld) with functionality related to options specific to your processor
- (Possibly) port other parts of the binutils (like objcopy and objdump)

Are you sure that the chip maker doesn't provide a port of GCC already (or some other C compiler)? And if you are the chip maker; are you sure that you actually need this custom processor, or could you make do with some existing processor that has good support (e.g. ARM, AVR, PIC, ...)?